# How to get class attribute from jQuery object at specified index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery object with dom elements(storing elements for waypoint.js). I want to get classes out of this object. Problem is that I can't do that selectively, because I got "... is not a function" error. I'm using jquery-3.2.1.min.js.

What I'm doing :

```
console.log($('.data')); // GOOD all data printed
console.log($('.data')[5]) // GOOD element at 5-th index printed
console.log($('.data').attr("class")); // printed class attribute of 1st element

console.log($('.data')[5].attr("class")); // BAD throwing "TypeError: $(...)[5].attr is not a function" 
console.log($('.data'[5]).attr("class")); // BAD printing some weird data, same result as 
console.log($(('.data')[5]).attr("class"));
```

Why can't I reach that class attribute(it's seems intuitve to do it that way) ?? How to do that ??

Comment: Try this to get 5th one? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp

Comment: @JohnKane Nope, it's just a css selector. I need to operate on exisiting jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log($('.data:eq(5)').attr("class"))`

JQuery's `eq` should get you there.  https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/